# Set a SIP sjphone as default

Tags: sip, skype, regedit

i use [SJphone](http://sjphone.org/) to make SIP calls
Everything work great until i install skype,
When i install skype the defauld program that open each time on click to call is Skype but i need to be SJPhone

ive made change in regedit

> HHEY_CLASSES_ROOT-callto-shell-open-command C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\SJLabs\SJphone\SJphone.exe /callto %l

and yes its work again, but only until i will open skype, after that by default will be again Skype

so, after each time i open skype i have to change

> HHEY_CLASSES_ROOT-callto-shell-open-command

i just wondering how to set once for all default SIP to be SJPhone

*NOTE: I make call via my php script

```
<script>
setTimeout(function()
{
    window.location = "callto:1<?php echo $myrow["phone"] ?>@sipprovider.com+type=sip+existingcalls=hangup";
}, 1000); // 1 seconds
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Menu "Tools", "Options", "Advanced Parameters", there are several options in Skype. I guess you just need to uncheck the one indicating to use Skype for "callto:" links.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply but this will not solve my problem, i use a php script to make call and its not a simple "click to call"

Comment: This doesn't change anything: changing the setting in Skype should prevent Skype to modify the registry! I think my answer may still be valid? unless you tried...

Comment: yes, i tried your advice and still calls start with skype